# C# Problems using Inheritance - My first time

Tags: c#, inheritance

I'm having a few issues while trying use Inheritance. I create a class named vehicle with some properties, and the another one named car which inherits the properties from vehicle, them when I run the code below, the C# compiler returns the following error:

> Program.cs (38,13): error CS0246: The namespace name or type 'car' could not be found. Need a policy using or an assembly reference?

Here's the code:

```
using System;

class vehicle
{
    public int MaxSpeed;
    public bool turnOn;
    public int wheels;

    public void car_on()
    {
        turnOn = true;
    }

    public void car_off()
    {
        turnOn = false;
    }

    class car : vehicle
    {
        public string name;
        public string color;

        public car(string name, string color)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.color = color;
            MaxSpeed = 220;
            wheels = 4;
            turnOn();
        }
    }
}

namespace Aula_28_herança
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            car c1= new car("ferrari","red");

            Console.WriteLine("Nome................:{0}", c1.name);
            Console.WriteLine("Cor.................:{0}", c1.color;
            Console.WriteLine("Velociade Máxima....:{0}", c1.MaxSpeed);
            Console.WriteLine("Quantiadade de Rodas:{0}", c1.wheels);
            Console.WriteLine("Status..............:{0}", c1.turnOn);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your class `car` is nested inside `vehicle`. That is not useful and  not recommended. Put them in separate files in the same folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your `carro` type public:

```
class veiculo{
....

    public class carro : veiculo{
      ...
    }
}
```

Ad use `veiculo.carro` for type:

```
veiculo.carro c1= new veiculo.carro("ferrari","vermelha");
```

See the docs on [Nested Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/nested-types):

> Regardless of whether the outer type is a class, interface, or struct, nested types default to private; they are accessible only from their containing type.